# ¿Cuál sería un ejemplo correcto de trama request autorización (1100) ISO 8583 para AMEX, codificada en EBCDIC?

Tags: php, hexadecimal

estoy intentado enviar a AMEX una prueba de autorización (MTI 1100) con ISO 8583-1993 con PHP, tengo a mano toda la documentación, pero no logro que llegue a destino.

Un ejemplo de trama que enviamos en hexadecimal ebcdic sería: **"F1F1F0F0703425C000408000F1F5F3F7F3F9F5F3F1F9F2F3F5F1F0F0F4F0F0F4F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F3F9F0F0F0F0F0F0F1F7F7F2F3F0F9F1F8F1F0F5F8F0F5F2F5F0F3F0F3F2F1F6F1F0F0F0F1F0F0F1F3F0F1F0F0F1F9F0F0F5F4F1F1F7F5F4F6F1F8F2F3F8F74040404040F0F3F2"**
no estoy incluyendo la longitud, es decir el MLI la misma se expresa en hexadecimal (ej. "0073" => 115 en decimal, donde 113 es la long. del mensaje + 2 del MLI(73).
Alguien pudo resolverlo?

Comment: "pero no logro que llegue a destino" que quiere decir esto?

Comment: Hola, no llega a su sistema test de pruebas (ATS), pero no llegaría porque estaría mal la estructura, aunque en su documentación menciona hexadecimal ebcdic

Comment: y como podemos saber que el error es ese y no otro??

Comment: tema de conexión no sería, porque otras tramas si han llegado, pero éstas han sido con otro formato (ascii/text, hexadecimal ascii), pero no como se especifica en la documentación, es decir en hexadecimal ebcdic

Comment: es decir, el problema podría ser la conversión de la trama cuando se envía, actualmente se envía el crudo en hexadecimal ebcdic (ejemplo arriba especificado)

Comment: solucionado, la trama en ebcdic está bien como figura arriba, luego se debe empaquetar la misma (pack('H')) y sobre eso calcular la longitud en decimal (se suma +2, por los dígitos que indican la longitud), a esa longitud pasarla a hexa (dechex) de 2 bytes (ej. '0073') y también empaquetar (pack('H'), para finalmente concatenar tanto longitud y trama y así poder enviar ese ''mensaje iso'.

Comment: Y si mejor lo pones en una respuesta??? responderte a vos mismo esta muy bien visto!

Answer (score 0):

solucionado, la trama en ebcdic está bien como figura arriba, luego se debe empaquetar la misma (**pack('H')**) y sobre eso calcular la longitud en decimal (se suma +2, por los dígitos que indican la longitud), a esa longitud pasarla a hexa (dechex) de 2 bytes (ej. '0073') y también empaquetar (**pack('H')**), para finalmente concatenar tanto longitud y trama y así poder enviar ese '**mensaje iso**'.